# Moving an upload field position in WordPress using CSS positions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wondering if someone can help with how to move an upload field from one position to another in WooCommerce. We've downloaded a plugin and can't really pay for these changes to be made.

The plugin generates a button under 'Add to Cart' to 'Upload Files', opens a div with a drop field, but this appears just above 'Recommended products' so visitors don't see the drop field. Ideally I want to move this to just under the product image and add-to-cart area, and above the product tabs.

The developer has advised me that the way to do this, is using CSS positions (relative or absolute), but I have no clue on how to do this.

Example site is:  http://cheapestprintuk.com/print/standard-business-cards/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how can anyone help you not seeing your CSS and HTML code?

Comment: Apologies, example is:

http://cheapestprintuk.com/print/standard-business-cards/

Just click the 'Upload' button and scroll down to see the issue. You'll have to select the options first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing is that bit of code of that plugin it's not outputting it on the right place for your theme.

Perhaps in the developer's theme where he worked on it, it was in the right place and for many other themes, but theme's features and stuff changes from theme to theme by its code, by the way they were built.

You could dig on it and try to fix it in the right way, but you can fix this by adding this bit of code on your CSS file:

```
#drop {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -680px;
}
```